# How to change list into data frama in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the list containing big data with time stamps. I would like to achieve the data frame with the time stamps as the first column and the values1, value2,... as next coumns.

My code gives out this small data frame

```
valList = ['value1','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6','value7','value8','value9','value10','value11','value12','value13','value14','value15'] 
pd.DataFrame([df],columns = valList)
```

[image: The data frame from my code]
Thats how the list looks like.
[image: List]

Comment: `pd.concat(df, axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find the Answers. I just created a new df, please compare it to your df.

```
import pandas as pd
x = [1,2,3,5]
y = [1,2,3,5]
z = [1,2,3,5]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z)), columns=["x", "y", "z"])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a DataFrame object from a list of pandas Series.

It also looks like those Series have already an appropriate column name.

The only thing you need to do is to concatenate those Series column-wise, making sure that they're all of the same length.

According to [pandas.concat documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat), you can do:

```
df = pd.concat([series_objs], axis=1)
```

where `[series_objs]` is your list of `pandas.Series` objects.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can split your data into timestamps and data values

```
#I am using a small list to demonstrate:

l=['2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00  28385.21','2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00  12280.00']
```

create another list from an empty list `k`

```
k=[]
for x in l:
  k.append(x.split('  ')) # there are 2 blank spaces in split to separate date with values
```

Now, `k` will look like this:

```
[['2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00', '28358'],
['2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00', '21358']]
```

Once, you get k will all the values, covert it into a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(k) # you can change the names of columns in this function according to your need

0   2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00   28358
1   2018-10-01 00:00:00+00:00   21358
```